# Appending a dictionary value to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

I'm having trouble appending the student dictionary value that coincides with key 'id' to a list. Any help is much appreciated!

```
students = list();
students.append( {'id':12345, 'first_name':'Alice', 
'last_name':'Anderson','assignments':[('assignment_1',0),('assignment_2',2), 
('assignment_3',3)]})
students.append({'id':22345, 'first_name':'John', 
'last_name':'Sparks','assignments':[('assignment_1',2),('assignment_2',3), 
('assignment_3',4)]})
students.append({'id':32345, 'first_name':'Taylor', 
'last_name':'Mason','assignments':[('assignment_1',3),('assignment_2',2), 
('assignment_3',3)]})

def return_passing(students):    
    grade_sum = 0
    counter = 0
    for s in students:  #loop thru students
        for assignment, grade in s['assignments']: 
            grade_sum += grade
            counter += 1
            average = grade_sum / counter
            lst = list()
        if average >= 2.0:
        lst.append((s['id']))
        return lst

return_passing(students) 

print(return_passing(students))
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error. I just cant seem to get the value to append to the list.

Comment: So the passing students are: 22345, 32345 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues with initializing things at the wrong place, so they get reset. Explanations for those are in the comments:

```
def return_passing(students):    
    lst = [] # initialize lst here
    for s in students:  #loop thru students
        grade_sum = 0 # reset these for each student
        counter = 0
        for assignment, grade in s['assignments']: 
            grade_sum += grade
            counter += 1
        # now that we have gone throug all assignments
        # compute average
        average = float(grade_sum) / counter # convert to float for precision
        if average >= 2.0:
            lst.append(s['id'])
    return lst # return only after you've gone through all students
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you.